# NgrX effect redirect angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have effect like this

```
  createAssignment$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(AssignmentActions.createAssignment),
      switchMap((action) =>
        this.assignmentService.createNewAssignment(action.assignmentTo).pipe(
          map((data) => AssignmentActions.createAssignmentSuccess({ createdAssignment: data }),
            catchError((error) => of(error))),
        )
      )
    ));
```

What I need is to redirect user to new page based on value from data, something like this

```
 this.router.navigate(data);
```

But I dont know when to do that, to make new effects or just under action? Anyone got similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using the `tap` operator after `map`, which will be invoked only if the operation succeeded:

```js
createAssignment$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
        ofType(AssignmentActions.createAssignment),
        switchMap((action) =>
            this.assignmentService
                .createNewAssignment(action.assignmentTo)
                .pipe(catchError((error) => of(error)))
        ),
        map((data) => AssignmentActions.createAssignmentSuccess({ createdAssignment: data })),
        tap((data) => { this.router.navigate(data); })
    )
);
```

Comment: Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected

Comment: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.28.2/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-misused-promises.md

Comment: I updated the answer, check it now, please.

Comment: Could you please confirm that you imported the `tap` operator from `rxjs/operators`?

Comment: Yes it is ok, this si eslint

Comment: Ok, I got it. You just need to add brackets `{}` around the `this.router.navigate(data)` so the eslint understand it correctly.

Comment: I updated the answer to include this change. Check it now, please.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating separate effect for redirect. New Effect encapsulates own logic and makes it also reusable. Listening for multiple actions in effect should not be uncommon pattern.

1. Inject Router in your Effects class **assignemnts.effects.ts**

   constructor(
   ...
   private readonly router: Router) {}
2. Your Code
   [image: Your code]

Redirect Effect that listens to your **AssignmnetActions.CreateAssignemntSuccess({assignment});**
Scenario: It will take the ID of the user in the assignment and redirect to /user-details page.

```
userPageRedirect$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AssignmnetActions.CreateAssignemntSuccess()),
      concatMap((action) => of(action).pipe(withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(getSelectedUserId))))),
      fetch({
        run: (action, userId: number) => {
          this.router.navigate([`/user-details/${userId}`]);
        },
      })
    ));
```